# What does this sentence mean?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was reading the book: " *Nanotechnology: A Gentle Introduction to the Next Big Idea*" and I came across this sentence:

> For these molecules to perform useful functions, they must be e**asy to
>   assemble and easy to recognize** and bind to by other molecules.

Who can explain this sentence? I have problem with "**easy to assemble and easy to recognize**" part?

It was in the paragraph below:-

> Generally, the molecules found in nature are complex and the source of
>   much dismay to beginning organic chemistry students. For these
>   molecules to perform useful functions, they must be **easy to assemble
>   and easy to recognize** and bind to by other molecules. They must also
>   be made by biological processes and have variable properties.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_recognition

Comment: This might refer to enzymes, for example - proteins which catalyze one specific reaction. "Easy to assemble", then, could imply that the body can only produce molecules in physological condition, i.e. no temperature above 42 °C, no high pressures, no highly corrosive or toxic compounds, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think the sentence means that the molecule the nanotechnician is using has to be quite easy for other molecules to interact with, either by chemically bonding to it or acting like a catalyst (or otherwise).